# openssl_encrypt works also to decrypt

Tags: php, openssl, cryptography

I made a mistake in my code writting `openssl_encrypt` to decrypt my passwords and it works. So maybe a stupid question but it is the same function ?

Here a test code:

```
$algo  = 'AES-256-CTR';
$key = "1P4s5W0rd_or_4nyTh1ng_3L53";
$ivlen=openssl_cipher_iv_length($algo);
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);

$data="test";
$b64data=base64_encode($data);
$encdata = openssl_encrypt($b64data,$algo,$key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$iv);

$b64decdata = openssl_encrypt($encdata,$algo,$key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$iv);
$decdata=base64_decode($b64decdata);

print "<br>data: $data";
print "<br>encdata: $encdata";
print "<br>decdata: $decdata";
print "<br>";
print "<br>key: $key";
print "<br>iv: $iv";
```

Which print:

```
data: test
encdata: ��v�>u
decdata: test

key: 1P4s5W0rd_or_4nyTh1ng_3L53
iv: �|t,ԏ�&6�����
```

So what's my mistake ? Where's the gremlin ?

Comment: Nope.. not the same. You've got a gremlin in your code, it definitely doesn't work.

Comment: see my edit please

Comment: Note that encryption is a binary, not character based operation. Encrypted data appears to be random bits/bytes and most do not have ASCII or any displayable character, that is why your output looks "funny". In order to correctly display binary output use hexadecimal (for people) or Base64 (for computers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encryption and decryption in CTR mode are the same, the algorithm generate a data stream based on the key and counter (iv) that is XOR'ed with the data. Given the same key and counter the same data stream is generated so encryption and decryption are the same operation.

See [CTR Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR)) for details, notice in the diagram that *encryption* is used for both encryption and decryption.